# XML Formatter for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

It is described at http://tools.android.com/recent that new `XML Formater` is available with SDK 12, I've installed one, but still can't see those settings for XML formatting like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand http://tools.android.com/recent, the page describes the latest checkins in the repository. In fact, the post by Tor Norbye that you refer to is dated 10 Aug, the same day XML-related code was merged into the main trunk, e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/7b69d9a11b46a364d816f6fd2791f201ac581fb6

In other words, these features do not seem to be in any release yet.

Comment: Yep i think thats also in the blog, theres a release post for adt 12 (=current version) from the 6.7.2011 with a message that any newer posts relate to adt 13. Also just checked for updates, everything new and shiny, yet I dont have these features too.

Answer (score 0):

It was installed automatically when I upgraded to the latest Eclipse plugin, so I guess it's automatic?

Comment: No, it wasn't. It wasn't added because I can't see these settings shown on the sreenshot.

Comment: Guess I'm not quite sure what you mean then. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [ADT 14 preview](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/adt-14-preview). I just installed it and I'm really glad to see new XML formatting capabilities. Or you can wait till stable version is out, so you will be able to install it automatically.